# Reversing a text and find same words - python

Tags: python, file, text, reverse

I have to write some code in python that will read all words from a text, reverse them and find which of them are the same in normal and reverse format. So far, I 've done this:

```
filename=raw_input("enter the file name: ")
fop=open(filename)
for line in fop:
  words=line.split()
li=[]
li.extend(words)
size=len(li)
for i in range(0,size/2):
    li[i], li[size-1-i] = li[size-1-i], li[i]
`enter code here`''.join(li)
```

but it doesn 't work, because if i give a text with more than one lines, it only processes the last line and doesn 't actually seem to reverse anything. Some help please?

Comment: You have indentation problem, all lines after `li=[]` till (`for i in range(0,size/2):`) must be on a same indentation with `words=line.split()`

Comment: Basically you want to check for palindromic strings in a file

Comment: Is the _homework_ tag gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do the following , you can check for reverse with `word == word[::-1]` that `word[::-1]` is reverse indexing  :

```
filename=raw_input("enter the file name: ")
with open(filename) as f :
    for line in f:
       for word in line.split() :
           if word == word[::-1]:
               print word
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do `line.strip()` before `.split()`, since [`line.split()` will truncate that line-ending newline anyway](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/4c1fc92fe062ad9d1a70). Great answer!

Comment: @AdamSmith yes , surely its so that , i have not idea myself why in the Earth i do that!!!;)maybe its because of a lot of coding today !

Comment: I do the same thing all the time -- it's just habit to strip a line before you operate on it!

Comment: @xtsiak you're welcome! you can tell this to community with voting and accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print just once the palindrome words you can use a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
print '\n'.join({w for w in open('file.txt).read().split() if w==w[::-1]})
```

Note that my answer doesn't filter any single letters, punctuation etc, in other words it depends on a loose and broad definition of what is a word.